# How do you use afconvert to convert from wav to aac caf WITHOUT RESAMPLING

Tags: iphone, audio, aac

I'm making an Iphone game, we need to use a compressed format for sound, and we want to be able to loop SEAMLESSLY back to a specific sample in the audio file (so there is an intro, then it loops back to an offset)

currently THE ONLY export process I have found that will allow seamless looping (reports the right priming and padding frame numbers, no clicking when looping ect) is using apple's afconvert to a aac format in a caf file.

but when we try and encode to lower bitrates, it automatically re samples the sound! we do NOT want to have the sound re sampled, every other encoder I have encountered has an option to set the output sample rate, but I can't find it for this one.

on another note, if anyone has had any luck with seamless looping of a compressed file format using audio queues, let me know.

currently I'm working off the information found at:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2009/qa1636.html

note that this DID work PERFECTLY when I left the bitrate for the encode at default (~128kbs)  but when I set it to 32kbps - with the -b option - it resampled, and looping clicks now.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be at least 48kbps.  32kbps will downsample to a lower sample rate.

Comment: I think you guys are confusing sample rate (typical values: 32kHz, 44.1kHz, 48kHz) with bit rate (typical values: 128kbps, 160kbps, 192kbps).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing sample rate (typical values: 32kHz, 44.1kHz, 48kHz) and bit rate (typical values: 128kbps, 160kbps, 192kbps).

For a bit rate, 32kbps is extremely low. Sound will have bad quality at this bit rate. You probably intended to set the sample rate to 32kHz instead, which is also not outright typical, but makes more sense.

When compressing to AAC and uncompressing back to WAV, you will not get the same audio file back, because in AAC, the audio data is represented in a completely different format than in raw wave. E.g. you can have shifts by few microseconds, which are necessary to convert to the compressed format. You can not completely get around this with any highly compressed format.

The clicking sound originates from the sudden change between two samples which are played in direct succession. This is likely taking place because the offset to which you jump back in your loop does not end up to be at exactly the same position in the AAC file as it was in the WAV file (as explained above, there can shifts by microseconds).

You will not get around these slight changes when compressing. Instead, you have to compensate for them after compression by adjusting the offset. That means you have to open the compressed sound file in an audio editor, e.g. Audacity, and manually find another offset close to the original one, which is suitable for looping.

How to find an offset which is suitable for looping?

Zoom in to the waveform's end. Look at how the waveform looks there. Then zoom in to the waveform at the original offset and search in its neighbourhood for an offset at which the waveform connects seamlessly to the end of the waveform.

For an example how this shoud look like, open the uncompressed audio file in the audio editor and examine the end of the waveform and the offset there.